# How to effectively filter spam emails that have two '@' symbols in the address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, email-filter

Apologies if this has been addressed before. We are seeing a companywide uptick in spam emails with attachments that use the following syntax for the 'From' email address (I apologize again that this didn't show up in my original post):

"Employee Name employeename@workdomain.comsomeothername@someotherdomain.com"

The first part of the address is definitely an employee's name and existing email address. What's different is that there is always another address/domain appended to the end of it. Most times this defeats the spam filters & Outlook rules already in place.  Without blocking every single "someotherdomain.com" that comes along, is there a way to filter out emails that have two '@' symbols in the address? Or conversely, mark as spam or junk any emails whose primary domain ('@workdomain.com') appears to be much longer (i.e., '@workdomain.com*')?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it is not feasible to use special wildcard characters such as an asterisk (*) in Outlook Junk Mail Options > Block Senders.

If the spam messages sender's email addresses are similar to "employee's name@workdomain.com@spamdomain.com", you may consider creating an inbox rule to move messages contain "workdomain.com@" to Junk Email folder:
[image]